# How can I fix size image in one part of bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want fix image in part one of bootstrap full size same the rest like picture 2.
plz help me.
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpwgb.png) and
[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djWXT.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want....use `background-image`, and set `background-size: cover`.

```html
<html>

<head>

  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />

  <style>
    body {
      padding: 50px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .container {
      width: 500px;
      height: 200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: black;
      display: inline-flex;
    }

    .food {
      background-image: url('https://live.staticflickr.com/3577/3388519531_d8b154f988.jpg');
      background-size: cover;
      width: 200px;
      margin: 12px;

    }

    .text {
      padding: 12px;
      color: white;

    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="food">

    </div>
    <div class="text">
      Hello this is your text
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```